# python use '|' in function param

Tags: python

I find someone def function like this:

```
import types
def start(caller_frame: types.FrameType | None = None):
```

But when I wrote the same code, it raised TypeError.

```
>>> def start(caller_frame: types.FrameType | None = None):
        pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    def start(caller_frame: types.FrameType | None = None):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'
```

I don't know why the '|' is unsupported but someone actually write it.
My python version is 3.9

Comment: That's 3.10 functionality.

Comment: oh neat!  I hate peppering my code with `Union`.